# Oiling fake Yunzi stones

Tags: go

I bought some "yunzi" stones that came in straw bowls, but they aren't translucent at all. They are fully opaque.

Considering the price paid (around 35 dollars, I bought it in Brazil), I think that they weren't the real deal, but they look nice anyway.

[image: picture of the stones]

Now, should/can I oil them? What are they made off?

Comment: Without knowing more about them it is impossible to answer your question.

Comment: I don't really think that there too many choices of material for a fake yunzi. They aren't plastic, they look like yunzi, their weight (I think) are like yunzi, they feel like some sort of ceramic glass, and not like pure glass stones (again like yunzi), but they aren't translucent green (like real yunzi). How many different types of material do YOU know like that? And about my question, oiling them will make they shine like oiled yunzi?

Comment: Considering that they are fake and you know they are fake makes it hard to assume what they could be made out of.

Comment: Are you so sure about that? Not trying to be disrespectful, but have you ever dealt with "yunzi" which are opaque? How many different material choices do people have for faking those stones? I don't think it could be more than one or two...

Comment: You failed in trying not to be respectful. @JoeW tried to help you, but he needed a bit more information. And you treated him like he was a clueless kid. 
You are the one with the question. If you want a real chance for a answer, please be nice and give the requested information.

Comment: He requested no specific information, merely saying that it was impossible to answer. What more can I tell about those stones that haven't been already told? Again, I don't think there are many choices of material for that as he seems to think.

Comment: You could have posted an image.

Comment: Added the requested image.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question asking to identify a type of stone/material based on a picture and a description; the fact that the stone can be used for the game Go doesn't help with the identification; Go knowledge doesn't help to answer the question.

Comment: Perhaps http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @GendoIkari, my primary questions was simply "should/can I oil [fake yunzi stones]?" Just that. Again I'm pretty sure that there aren't many choices of material for this, and people who know them might be able to give a simple: "that is probably glass/ceramic/etc". Anyway, I'm a member of several stack exchange sites, and never saw such a bad response to a question.

Comment: I'm not trying to be negative or respond badly or anything; I simply don't think that this question actually has very much to do with board games at all.

Comment: Asking questions and trying to get a better understanding is a bad response?

Comment: @JoeW Asking questions to try to clarify what is being asked or to get additional information is a fine response. Having said that, your first two posts in the comments weren't doing either of these things. Both are statements that read as "Your question can't be answered."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest a *spot test*. Try oiling a small, inconspicuous section of one stone.

Comment: Tried in one stone and it didn't seem to have any adverse effects. It made then shiner and looked much smoother. Done on everything.