# How does White survive in this corner?

Tags: go, tsumego

This is from a game between two high-ranking professionals I saw on TV.  Hopefully I copied it right.

There doesn't quite seem to be enough from after W1.  Let me show you [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Nocs.jpg)]:

```
$$Wc
$$ . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ . . . X . . . . . . |
$$ . O X . X . . . 1 . |
$$ . . . . . . X . X . |
$$ . . . . . . . X X . |
$$ . X . . X X X O X O |
$$ . . . X O O O O O O |
$$ . . . . X . . . X . |
$$ --------------------|
```

If Black moves first, perhaps there's not enough from after B2 and W3 ?

```
$$Wc
$$ . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ . . . X . . . . . . |
$$ . O X . X . . . O . |
$$ . . . . . . X . X . |
$$ . . . . . . . X X . |
$$ . X . 3 X X X O X O |
$$ . . . X O O O O O O |
$$ . . . . X 2 . . X . |
$$ --------------------|
```

If White has just a little bit more time, we can put a white stone at A. Not even.

```
$$c
$$ . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ . . . X . . . . . . |
$$ . O X . X . . . O . |
$$ . . . . . . X . X . |
$$ . . . . . . . X X . |
$$ . X . . X X X O X O |
$$ . . . X O O O O O O |
$$ . . . . X 2 . . X . |
$$ --------------------|
```

So what are they thinking?

Comment: You say a White stone at _A_, but you have not marked _A_; perhaps you mean 2?

Comment: P.S. If you meant A15, perhaps you should add a `c` to your diagram headers to show the coördinates. It would also be interesting to know what happened next in the game – or was it just a snippet on a random news item? Anyway, like you, I have difficulty understanding what is going on. Maybe 1 makes a ko threat, but I do not know if that is relevant. The entire position (in the linked image) looks fairly complicated.

Comment: @PJTraill as far as I can tell... White is [dead](https://senseis.xmp.net/?LifeAndDeath).  and maybe it's trying to put in some [aji](https://senseis.xmp.net/?Aji)... would you like me to link you to the video?? [ [here](https://youtu.be/MQo4HoGHVrU?t=1h20m) ]

Comment: It would indeed be worth linking to the video in your question. I see there that the B stone at Q5 was played _after_ W 1. There is also a ko-fight going on at 12x{I,J}, so moves may be ko-threats; after Q5, White connects the ko, so he has ignored a Black threat. At 1:26:40 W apparently resigns during a countdown; this can also mean that previous moves were setting the scene for resignation: see my question [What is looking for a place to resign in go?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/35599/what-is-looking-for-a-place-to-resign-in-go) and https://senseis.xmp.net/?HowToResign.

Comment: Having added coördinates to your diagrams, I realise that I wrote A15 when I meant P1!

Comment: In the video, Q5 is not present when 1 is played.

Comment: It looks like 1 threatens Q4 Q5 T5 connecting out to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the original question: White's corner is **unconditionally dead**, it cannot be rescued even with White playing first. The points `P1` and `R1` are *miai*, when White takes one of them Black takes the other.

In the actual game White uses the *aji* left in the corner for some Ko threats, that's all White can get out of the local situation.